# Jgroups UDP bind_addr creates two clusters instead one

Tags: java, jgroups

I have two servers in the same network (10.40.20.1 and 10.40.20.2), and clustered cache with UDP configurated like this:

With this configuration two clusters are created in network (each with one server):

```
  <UDP bind_addr="127.0.0.1" mcast_addr="212.1.2.1" mcast_port="49960"
                      ip_ttl="64" ip_mcast="true"   
                      mcast_send_buf_size="150000" mcast_recv_buf_size="80000"  
                      ucast_send_buf_size="150000" ucast_recv_buf_size="80000"  
                      loopback="false" />
```

With this configuration it is better, one cluster is created with two servers (10.40.20.1 and 10.40.20.2)

```
 <UDP bind_addr="10.40.20.1" mcast_addr="212.1.2.1" mcast_port="49960"
                      ip_ttl="64" ip_mcast="true"   
                      mcast_send_buf_size="150000" mcast_recv_buf_size="80000"  
                      ucast_send_buf_size="150000" ucast_recv_buf_size="80000"  
                      loopback="false" />
```

I use jgroups 2.4.1, why I must provide real ip addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first node binds to `127.0.0.1` so it won't see the other node.  This would only work if both nodes were running on the same host.

That's why you need to set `bind_addr` to a real NIC.

You could also set `bind_addr` to a symbolic name, e.g. `site_local`, then any site local IP address will be picked.

Alternatively, you could set it to a regexp, e.g. `bind_addr=match_interface:eth0.\*` which picks any interface starting with `eth0`, or `bind_addr=match-address:192.168.5.\*` which picks any NIC with an address starting with `192.168.5`.

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#Transport